# Using .replace() in python to avoid error as below

Tags: python

Here I am creating a function which replaces a word in text with asterisks. E.g for a text like ('boy meets girl') i should replace boy with "***" and receive ("*** meets girl") I have created the function and the rest as shown below. PS: I'm new to this.

```py
def censor(text, word):

    words = str(text)
    stars = '*' * len(word)
    for i in words:
        if i == word:
            words.replace(i, stars)
    return text

print (censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack"))
```

The problem is that it returns my exact text without the change

Comment: Strings are immutable; methods create new strings. You have to assign the result or it is lost. Note that your code has several other problems, for example it checks whether a *character* (``for i in str(text)``) equals a word (``if i == word``).

Answer (score 0):

`replace` returns a new string, so you need to overwrite text:

```
def censor(text, word):
    stars = '*' * len(word)
    text = words.replace(word, stars)
    return text

print (censor("boy meets girl", "boy"))
```

Output:

```
*** meets girl
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop and having `words` variable is unnecessary.

```
def censor(text, word):

    stars = '*' * len(word)
    text = text.replace(word, stars)
    return text

print(censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack"))
```

---

```
this **** is wack ****
```

Comment: Thank you, It really helped

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to just call string.replace without doing the extra loops. But the downside is that you might censor partial words, if your target word is a part of another word.

```
def censor(text, word):
    stars = '*' * len(word)
    return text.replace(word, stars)

print (censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def censor(text, word):
    stars = '*' * len(word)
    return (text.replace(word, stars))
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

To provide alternative to str.replace() which will result: cowboy -> cow***, boycott -> ***cott etc and address OP request for 'replaces a word in text with asterisks'

Can be described as: split string to words and check equality to censor word (not addressed here, but on should take into account case sensitivity and punctuation as well - Boy will not be censored as well as boy.):

```
def censor(text, word):
    words = text.split()
    return ' '.join('*' * len(item) if item==word else item for item in words)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `str.split` do not preserve spaces. E.g. `a string with         lot     of        spaces` would becomes `a string with lot of spaces`. **EDIT:** SO stripped the spaces from the first string but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, without any doubt it will not preserve whitespaces. I get the idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to censor complete word I would recommend something like this:

```
import re

def censor(text, word, ignorecase=True):
    # Get a new string we will return
    censored = str()

    # If we want to ignore the case, make the given word lowercase
    if ignorecase:
        word = word.lower()

    # Loop through all words in the given text
    for s in re.split(r'(\s+)', text):

        # Censor the word if it is the one we are looking for
        if (s.lower() if ignorecase else s) == word:
            s = '*' * len(word)

        # Add the current word to the result string
        censored += s

    # Return the censored string
    return censored


print(censor("this hAck is wack HaCk when a duck is quhacking", "hAcK")) # this **** is wack **** when a duck is quhacking
```